# Angular 8 and Service worker hash mismatch

Tags: angular, progressive-web-apps, angular-service-worker

I have an Angular 8 app deployed to a server with a service worker enabled/registered. The issue we seem to be getting is that randomly the site loads an older version instead of the latest version of the site.
I assumed it is because of the service worker so when I go to /ngsw/state I get the following errors on the debug:

NGSW Debug Info:

```
Driver state: EXISTING_CLIENTS_ONLY (Degraded due to failed initialization: Hash mismatch (cacheBustedFetchFromNetwork): https://mysite/index.html: expected 3103c76d8444cfb504f58967dfb578826e29a778, got f5405776b6b8852db45bf2e118999dffc33ddaea (after cache busting) Error: Hash mismatch (cacheBustedFetchFromNetwork): https://mysite/index.html: expected 3103c76d8444cfb504f58967dfb578826e29a778, got f5405776b6b8852db45bf2e118999dffc33ddaea (after cache busting) at PrefetchAssetGroup.<anonymous> (https://mysite/ngsw-worker.js:699:35) at Generator.next (<anonymous>)at fulfilled (https://mysite/ngsw-worker.js:320:62)) Latest manifest hash: f2dce0f16ab8d88dc3d3701ffabc1475507649be Last update check: 1m52s425u

=== Version f2dce0f16ab8d88dc3d3701ffabc1475507649be ===

Clients: 0fc1bc95-193d-4a3a-9953-6df0bccc7b6c

=== Idle Task Queue ===
Last update tick: 1m52s327u
Last update run: 1m47s326u
Task queue:

Debug log:

[1m59s831u] TypeError(Failed to fetch, TypeError: Failed to fetch) Driver.fetch(https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js) [1m59s147u] TypeError(Failed to fetch, TypeError: Failed to fetch) Driver.fetch(https://stats.g.doubleclick.net/j/collect?t=dc&aip=1&_r=3&v=1&_v=j89&tid=UA-151661671-2&cid=1149317656.1606203988&jid=704609344&gjid=982880217&_gid=688801729.1617694502&_u=QACAAEAAAAAAAC~&z=1082920103) [1m52s575u] Error(Hash mismatch (cacheBustedFetchFromNetwork): https://mysite/index.html: expected 3103c76d8444cfb504f58967dfb578826e29a778, got eee6f2cd04ab4f02dbfdaa3e424007927721b6cb (after cache busting), Error: Hash mismatch (cacheBustedFetchFromNetwork): https://mysite/index.html: expected 3103c76d8444cfb504f58967dfb578826e29a778, got eee6f2cd04ab4f02dbfdaa3e424007927721b6cb (after cache busting) at PrefetchAssetGroup.<anonymous> (https://mysite/ngsw-worker.js:699:35) at Generator.next (<anonymous>) at fulfilled (https://mysite/ngsw-worker.js:320:62)) Error occurred while updating to manifest d5b4ea310e6ff5fbb7a547834e701efb6d6dcbf7 [1m52s327u] Error(Hash mismatch (cacheBustedFetchFromNetwork): https://mysite/index.html: expected 3103c76d8444cfb504f58967dfb578826e29a778, got f5405776b6b8852db45bf2e118999dffc33ddaea (after cache busting), Error: Hash mismatch (cacheBustedFetchFromNetwork): https://mysite/index.html: expected 3103c76d8444cfb504f58967dfb578826e29a778, got f5405776b6b8852db45bf2e118999dffc33ddaea (after cache busting) at PrefetchAssetGroup.<anonymous> (https://mysite/ngsw-worker.js:699:35) at Generator.next (<anonymous>) at fulfilled (https://mysite/ngsw-worker.js:320:62)) Error occurred while updating to manifest d5b4ea310e6ff5fbb7a547834e701efb6d6dcbf7 [1m52s327u] TypeError(Failed to fetch, TypeError: Failed to fetch) Driver.fetch(https://mysite/) [1m47s325u] TypeError(Failed to fetch, TypeError: Failed to fetch) Driver.fetch(https://mysite/ngsw.json?ngsw-cache-bust=0.564237218729041) [1m47s325u] Check for update aborted. (Client or server offline.)
```

When I check the index.html file on the server I see there's no difference (extra line added after deploy or any other changes) to what is built after ng build. I also checked the hash of the file from the server and it shows the correct hash which is: 3103c76d8444cfb504f58967dfb578826e29a778, so I am not sure how it is getting a completely different hash altogether..

The only difference I can see is that when I'm on the site and go into developer tools the index.html file being served has an extra line few lines(I think it's coming from our monitoring js agent)then what is on the server itself. Not sure if this could be the cause?

Any guidance on where/what could be causing this will be highly appreciated